# Testing Paris model with PHPSpec2

Tags: php, phpspec

I have a [Paris](https://github.com/kevinsperrine/paris) model, with something like this:

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function authenticate($signature)
    {
        $hash = hash_hmac('sha256', $this->email, $this->password);

        if ($hash == $signature)
            $this->_authenticated = true;

        return $this->_authenticated;
    }
}
```

I would like to spec this with [PHPSpec2](https://github.com/phpspec/phpspec2), but i'm having some issues. I want to do something like:

```
$this->authenticate('test')->shouldReturn(true);
```

But how do i access the authenticate() method in my spec? I think the answer might be very simple, but i really can't get my head around it...

Comment: I'm not familiar with PHPSpec, but you're returning a boolean, not an object with the method shouldReturn.

Comment: Hmm, I think this is how PHPSpec functions... Like ruby's RSpec.

Comment: according to the [PHPSpecs Docs](http://www.phpspec.net/#manual) what you have should work as long as you're calling authenticate on the correct object IE: ```$this```. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: I'm not by the computer now, but you're right. I'm having a hard time figuring out what $this is refering to. I will try to post some of the errors i get later. Thanks!

Comment: inside the authenticate method, ```$this``` refers to the ORM object instance of ```User``` (the current record being authenticated)... ```$user = Model::factory('User')->find_one($id); $user->authenticate()->shouldReturn(true);```

Comment: When i run that it get: "Fatal error:  Class 'spec\Model' not found in /home/peter/www/cc-core/spec/User.php on line 21" - So it is some sort of namespace issue?

Comment: Should I stub or mock the Model::factory() method? Then I won't be able to test the database interaction?

Comment: Can you gist/pastebin your whole spec?

Comment: Thanks Marcello, but I changed my mind and went back to PHPUnit on this project... I really love the idea about PHPSpec, but i need something a litte more well-documented at this moment!

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

namespace spec;

use PHPSpec2\ObjectBehavior;

class UserSpec extends ObjectBehavior
{
    function it_should_be_initializable()
    {
        $this->shouldHaveType('User');
    }

    function it_should_authenticate_if_proper_signature_given()
    {
        $signature = '...';
        $this->setEmail('...');
        $this->setPassword('...');

        $this->authenticate($signature)->shouldReturn(true);
    }
}
```

You need to create you signature out of email and password first in the spec. Implement some setters for email and password in the User class as well. In general that should do the trick :)

Answer (score 1):

Couple of thoughts on this.

Your User Model is working with a collaborator in order to fulfil it's own behaviour - this collaborator being the hash_hmac function. The golden rule with PHPSpec is  [Subject Under Specification](http://everzet.com/post/33178339051/sus-collaborators), work on one class at a time and consider the implementation details of collaborators later.  I've found this has helped me design classes with separation of concerns principles in mind and I often find myself asking the question - what does this class actually care about?

For example, your `UserModel` shouldn't really care about which hashing algorithm your system is using to protect passwords. It could however know about an object, call it `HashingProvider`, that has the ability to hash a password, or even to just receive one or more strings and return some sort of hash representation.

By re-architecting your `UserModel` in such a way, you'll be able to take full advantage of Mocking ([great talk here](http://www.slideshare.net/marcello.duarte/mocking-demystified)) in PHPSpec to concentrate on implementing your `UserModel` first and then move on to the `HashingProvider`

Your spec might look like this:

```
<?php

namespace spec;
use PHPSpec2\ObjectBehavior;

class User extends ObjectBehavior
{
   function it_should_be_initializable()
   {
        $this->shouldHaveType('User');
   }

   /**
    * @param /Some/HashingProvider $hashProvider
    */
   function it_should_authenticate_if_proper_signature_given($hashProvider)
   {
      $this->setEmail('email');
      $this->setPassword('password');
      $hashProvider->hash('email', 'password')->willReturn('signature');

      $this->authenticate('signature', $hashProvider)->shouldReturn(true);
   }

   /**
    * @param /Some/HashingProvider $hashProvider
    */
   function it_should_not_authenticate_if_invalid_signature_given($hashProvider)
   {
      $this->setEmail('email');
      $this->setPassword('password');
      $hashProvider->hash('email', 'password')->willReturn('signature');

      $this->authenticate('bad_signature', $hashProvider)->shouldReturn(false);
   }
}
```

Your User model can then use that collaborator in the way in which your spec describes:

```
<?php
class User extends Model
{
    public function authenticate($signature, $hashProvider)
    {
        $hash = $hashProvier->hash($this->email, $this->password);

        if ($hash == $signature)
            $this->_authenticated = true;

        return $this->_authenticated;
    }
}
```